# Convert Bash script to Perl/VBS/any other windows compatible language

Tags: perl, bash, powershell, vbscript, batch-file

I got a bash script that was made for transferring files from a Sandbox to a host.
The files in the sandboxdirectory get transferred only if they are younger, meaning they have been "touched" before. Unfortunately, cygwin is causing trouble under windows so I need the script in another language or I need something that works like cygwin under windows.
The script is just about 20 lines, but i don't have any clue how to convert it to another language(especially commands like touch, make, gcc, getopts, set -e)
I'd be happy if someone finds this easy to do and converts it:

```
# EXITING SCRIPT IF ERROR OCCURS
set -e

FORCE=false
JUSTPRINT=

# if parameter -f is given, force to transfer all files(no matter if new or not)
# if -n is given checking files
while getopts fn opt 2>/dev/null
do
case $opt in
f) FORCE=true ;;
n) JUSTPRINT="-n" ;;
?) ;;
esac
done

# deleting parsed options from command line
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`


# refresh files that came with -f
if [ \( $FORCE = true \) -a \( $# -gt 0 \) ]
then
touch -c $@
fi

# Targets (dummy files for timestamp)
TARGETS=`for filename
     do
       if [ -f $filename ]
       then
         echo "../transport_dummies/\`basename $filename\`.dum"
       else
         echo "$filename"
       fi
     done`

# call script directory
echo $0
cd `dirname $0`

# creating sysfilterL.exe
if [ ! -f sysfilterL ]
then
echo "sysfilterL is created."
gcc sysfilter.c -o sysfilterL
fi

# Call Transport-Makefile with target
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
make --warn-undefined-variables $JUSTPRINT -f transportDE.mk reset $TARGETS
send_queueed
else
make --warn-undefined-variables $JUSTPRINT -f transportDE.mk
fi
```

Comment: Why does everyone give me bad rep instead of helping me?

Comment: because this is not a "do my work for me" site. you need to ask more specific, answerable, questions. Read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: There are Windows bash ports, e.g. in cygwin, msys.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the shell script to a batch file, which is covered here: [How do I convert a bash shell script to a .bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200018/how-do-i-convert-a-bash-shell-script-to-a-bat-file)

Also here is a list of corresponding commands in bash and batch: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of people that can. You can for instance. Read the linked page. Understand it. Convert what you can. Then come back here and ask specific questions about the commands that you cannot figure out....That or hire someone to do your work for you.