# UNIX script to run on WINDOWS

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, cygwin

I got a couple of questions,

Is there any way to make a UNIX script run under a windows OS without any add-on like CYGWIN?

Is there any way to transform a UNIX script to a windows batch script, so that i can run it in windows cmd ?

I searched for that but i get referred to the UNIX command win2unix or unix2win , the ones that transform a file from/to windows/UNIX format.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The way to execute UNIX scripts on Windows are tools like Cygwin. Transforming a bash script into Windows batch is like translating a program from PHP to C (or whatever combination): it involves learning the basics so that you can rewrite it.

Comment: You can see more discussion in this thread: [How do I convert a bash shell script to a .bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200018/how-do-i-convert-a-bash-shell-script-to-a-bat-file)

Comment: It's not possible to run a shell script under UNIX without a shell (and some other programs) either. Only difference to Windows is that a `sh`-compatible shell is normally part of every UNIX-like system whereas under Windows it's not. But that's just coincidence, or bad luck, or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: transforming would be: writing a batch or powershell script with the same functionality. "Transforming" is a bit like "google translate"

Comment: @Damon: I am afraid I don't follow you. It is also not possible to run a shell script in Windows without a shell (and some other programs) either, and a `.bat`-compatible shell is normally part of every Windows system whereas `sh`-compatible scripts it's not. I don't understand how terms like "only difference", "just coincidence", or "bad luck" can be applied to this situation. Your comment is confusing...

Comment: @Aacini: The apparent "issue" is that you can't run a `bash` script (assuming `bash`, but could be any shell) under Windows without "something like Cygwin" (or MSYS, GNUWin, etc). But truth is, you can't under Unix, either. Only under Unix, a compatible shell _happens to be_ always-present (well, not _always_, but usually). It is not surprising at all (or shouldn't be, in my opinion) that you need a script interpreter to run a script. Just like you need something like "Word" to open a Word document.

Comment: @Damon: Suppose that the question would be in the opposite sense: "Is there any way to make a Windows batch script run under a UNIX OS without any add-on?", and that my comment would be: "It's not possible to run a shell script under Windows without a shell (and some other programs) either. Only difference to UNIX is that a .bat-compatible shell is normally part of every Windows system whereas under UNIX it's not. But that's just coincidence, or bad luck, or whatever you want to call it". Do you think that this comment would have any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer for this old question is to install and run light Unix-like emulators. Here are some options:

- [MinGW](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/) -- native Windows port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)
- [MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/) -- command line terminal called mintty, bash, version control systems like git and subversion, tools like tar and awk and even build systems like autotools
- [GitBash](https://gitforwindows.org/) -- BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home

The above list installs micro environments much lighter than a typical Cygwin install. Also, in my experience most Bash scripts run on par with native Linux environments in these environments.

Yet another option is [installing a Linux Subsytem like WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Yet another option is converting Bash to DOS by hand or with partial assistance of something like [Bash-to-BAT converter](https://daniel-sc.github.io/bash-shell-to-bat-converter/), which isn't very full featured, and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html#:%7E:text=Appendix%20N.%20Converting%20DOS%20Batch%20Files%20to%20Shell,string%20comparison%20test%20%2032%20more%20rows%20).

Comment: Also, the `dos2unix` utility may need to be run against any `Bash` script edited in a Windows environment to convert Windows carriage returns to `LF`s that are understandable by Bash.

Answer (score 2):

I know you don't want an "add on", but if this may help : you can download [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) (or a portable version of it), which will come with many things, including many unix utilities (shell, etc) and lots you can download from their website.

The portable version is the most convenient (and you can carry it on your usb key, for example)

It's quite slower than cygwin/etc (most commands are emulated via some master binary, and many shell "builtins" becomes instead invocations of that binary, for example), but very portable and neat.

Other solutions (converting, etc) probably will also entail a binary of some sort, so I recommand the above, as it's very portable and gives you a kind of "mini unix inside windows"