# OpenSSL for Windows: Read https certificate

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, openssl

I'm trying to convert a bash script for Linux to run in Windows batch as well. Amongst several commands, there is also an OpenSSL command which reads a certificate from an https server and stores it in a variable. The bash command is:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $SERVER_IP:443/login </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > mycertfile.pem
```

I've installed OpenSSL in my Windows machine from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). I prefered the "Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.0e Light" version of OpenSSL.

How is this command transferred to Windows logic? Any ideas?

Comment: Beyond changing `$SERVER_IP` to `%SERVER_IP%` and `/dev/null` to `nul`, I don't know what else would need to be done, since I don't have OpenSSL installed.

Comment: Also see [How do I convert a bash shell script to a .bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3200018/608639) But you should ask specific question for specific problems.